# Delete repeated words between brackets inline

Tags: shell, text-processing, regular-expression

Our input looks something like

```
2012-04-17  [GBPGBP]
2012-04-13  [GBP GBP]
2012-04-13  [GBP]
2012-04-11  [GBPGBP]
2012-04-11  [GBP GBP]
2012-04-10  [GBPGBP]
2012-04-06  [GBP GBP GBP]
2012-04-17  [GBPGBP]
2012-04-13  [GBP CDN]
2012-04-13  [GBP]
2012-04-11  [GBPCDN]
2012-04-11  [GBP DL DL]
2012-04-10  [PSGBP]
2012-04-06  [PS PS]
```

And we'd like to get output like

```
2012-04-17  [GBP]
2012-04-13  [GBP]
2012-04-13  [GBP]
2012-04-11  [GBP]
2012-04-11  [GBP]
2012-04-10  [GBP]
2012-04-06  [GBP]
2012-04-17  [GBP]
2012-04-13  [GBP CDN]
2012-04-13  [GBP]
2012-04-11  [GBPCDN]
2012-04-11  [GBP DL]
2012-04-10  [PSGBP]
2012-04-06  [PS]
```

Basically delete any repeated string within the brackets. Any suggestions?

Comment: Define *string*. The first line suggests that a simple set of nested loops will suffice (slowly), but the second line shows you expect white space to be treated as special. What do you *really* want? Do you have a dictionary of 'words' that can appear?

Comment: @ams Actually yes: it'd be `GBP`, `CDN` or `PS` in every case. I _really_ want the output brackets to give me the unique set of that dictionary that appears within the input brackets, ignoring white space. If the brackets have `GBP` multiple times, regardless of separation I want it condensed to a single `GBP`. I wish I could do something like `tr -s "GBP" |tr -s "CDN"|tr -s "PS"` but `tr -s` only works for single characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sed -e ': a' -e 's/\(\[[^][]*\)\([A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]*\)\([^][]*\)\2/\1\2\3/' -e 't a'
```

- `: a` sets a label at the beginning of the script.
- `s/\(wibble\)\(foo\)\(bar\)\2/\1\2\3/` replaces wibblefoobarfoo by wibblefoobar.
- `[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]*` matches two or more letters
- `t a` loops back to the label `a` if the previous `s` command made a replacement.

Comment: I ended up going with `sed -e ': a' -e 's/\(\[[^][]*\)\([A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]\)\([^][]*\)\2/\1\2\3/' -e 't a'` since the wild card seemed to be only deleting the last two letters of a repeat. I changed other code to ensure that all the matches would be three characters long. Thanks!